# the default option is not coming in select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVIko.png)I want  to add the default option select in select tag but it taking the default value from the api data

Here the select should come rather than taking default value from  api

Comment: Please provide some code so others can give suggestions.

Comment: <select className='form-select' aria-label="Default select example" onChange={handleApplicationType} value={applicationType}>
                            {applicationTypeOptions?.map((name, index) =>
                                    (<option value={name} key={index}>{name}</option>)
                            )}
                            </select>

Comment: Got it, For which element you required default selection?

Comment: Code belongs in the question as text, not in the comments and not in images. [Edit] it

Comment: The first option need to be the default value, check [Mozilla example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#try_it), please include the code in text as it makes easier for  more community members to test the code and hence you can expect more better quality answers

Answer (score 0):

By **selected** props you can make it default selected:
(Note: I am pasting example please change as per your requirement.)

```
<select name="plan" id="plan">
    <option value="free">Free</option>
    <option value="starter" selected>Starter </option>
    <option value="professional">Professional</option>
    <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
</select>
```

So Here **starter (second one)** will be default selected.